# How to use Amazon DynamoDB instead of couchDB for store off-chain data in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to implement Off-Chain data in hyperledger fabric I checked https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/off_chain_data however instead of couch_DB I want to implement on Amazon DynamoDB.can we do that or there is no option to replace couchDB?

Any help will be great for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can be using any DB to store off-chain data.

Let see the process of this example do.

- Listen to block events in [code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/1343ccb6282e4ecab23ccdba0d1b2158cf7dfd55/off_chain_data/blockEventListener.js#L119) ([document about addBlockListener function](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Network.html#addBlockListener__anchor))
- If detect a new block added, it will get data of this block and save to DB you config by call function [writeValuesToCouchDBP](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/1343ccb6282e4ecab23ccdba0d1b2158cf7dfd55/off_chain_data/blockProcessing.js#L109). You should modify this to using Amazon DynamoDB (or any DB you want) instead of CouchDB

Comment: Hi @harisato Thanks for you information  however I get know the function where we need to change but issue with configure DynamoDB instead of couchDB as couch DB use KVWriteSet value into the OffChain storage(CouchDB) but couldn't get any info how we can set in DynamoDB